# django: How can i get multiple instances of model Userinfo when each instance of Userinfo has multiple instances in Education model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models that I am working with. First one is a education model in which one user can enter multiple educational qualifications instances:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    degree_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
    institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    date_start = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=25)
    date_end = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=1000)
```

Second Model is the 'User info' model in which one user can have maximum one instance:

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_info = models.ForeignKey(User_info,related_name='user_info',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    profile_pic = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=160, null=True,blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    current_salary = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    japanese_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    english_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    career_level = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    expected_salary = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    job_role = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

When I use any query to get any instance of 'User info' like:

```
Userinfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

How can i related both models so that when looping through Userinfo, I should be able to get multiple instances of it in Education model. How should I change my models and query them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you already have a foreign key to the User model inside your `Education` model. There is no need for a foreign key in the `UserInfo` Model. You can fetch all the `Education` instances for a given user just by making an extra call:

```
Education.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

or you can change `request.user` to the actual user that you need to get.

**EDIT:**

without making any changes to your code, you can get the multiple instances in the following way:

example views.py

```
def myView(request):
    user_info = Userinfo.objects.get(user=request.user) #using get since only 1 instance always
    educations = Education.objects.filter(user=request.user) #fetching all the instances for the education

    context_dict = {"user_info": user_info}
    educations_list = []



    for e in educations:
        educations_list.append(e)
        # do whatever you need with the educations
        # you can access user_info fields just by `user_info.field_name`
        # and you can access the current education fields by `e.field_name`
    context_dict["educations"] = educations_list

    return render(request, "template.html", context_dict)
```

example usage in template.html

```
{% if user_info %}
    <p>{{ user_info.field_name }}</p>

    {% if educations %}
        {% for e in educations %}
            <div>{{ e.field_name }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT 2 (including multiple userinfo instances)**

views.py

```
def myView(request):
    user_infos = Userinfo.objects.filter() # fetch all instances
    context_dict = {}

    result = []

    for u in user_infos:
        temp = []
        educations_list = []
        educations = Education.objects.filter(user=u.user) # fetch educations for the currently iterated user from user_infos
        for e in educations:
            educations_list.append(e)
        temp.append(u) # append the current user_info
        temp.append(educations_list) # append the corresponding educations
        result.append(temp)
    context_dict["result"] = result
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

template.html

```
{% if result %}
    {% for r in result %}
        <div>{{ r.0 }}</div> <!-- r.0 is your currently iterated user_info can be used like: r.0.profile_pic for example -->
        {% if r.1 %}
            {% for e in r.1 %}
                <div>e.degree_name</div> <!-- e is the current education on the current user_info -->
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

the code in the views.py is not perfect and might be worth to refactor a bit (how to build the final dictionary), but i believe this will give you an idea of how to do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually that's not what I am looking for, I am looking for getting UserInfo instance along with all the education instances of the user in one query.

Comment: There is a situation in my project where i need all userinfo along with his education in one query so that i can use for loop and print all the user's info along with their respective education.

Comment: @jencko I am sorry, but I will not be able to help you out with achieving that in 1 query, although I can give you pointers on how to do my way if you would like this approach.

Comment: @jencko see my answer. is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: @jencko I have updated my answer, hopefully this is what you need!

Comment: @jencko included example usage as well.

Comment: @N.Ivanov Thankyou so much but I am afraid this method is only good for single instance of userinfo. Can you also give me a way to get mutiple userinfo along with their education ?

Comment: @jencko I have included a new edit in my answer that should handle multiple user_info instances. Hope this was helpful, and may I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as Accepted, so that future visitors can find it easily and solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanov I would have accepted if it was working for me. You didn't read my last comment carefully. I am talking about getting not only multiple instances of 'education' model but also for Userinfo model. If I want to show multiple instances of Userinfo (along with their instances of education  if any), then your way is not successful. I would be happy to accept your answer if you could give me answer to it or any easier way to go about this problem. I am also open to change my model structure.

Comment: @jencko in my **Second Edit** I have included on how to get **Multiple** userinfo instances with their respectful education instances. I have indeed given the correct answer, maybe you were reading my **first Edit**?

Comment: @N.Ivanov Cool, thanks. I found one more easier answer too though. But thanks again, I have accepted it and gave it up-vote as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
ui = Userinfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

this query will give you all the instances of `Userinfo` for `request.user`. you can access the value of `Education` attributes with looping like this:

```
for u in ui:
    ui.education.degree_name
    # and so on for other fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your UserInfo model can have a OneToOne relationsship with user and then do something like

```
UserInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).education_set.all()
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck!